# GitHub Actions stuck on yarn build step for React app continous integration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, continuous-integration, yarnpkg, github-actions

I am trying to create a simple continous integration workflow for my React app in which for every new pull request to master branch I run the unit tests and create build. I have deployed the yaml configuration file for GitHub Actions to my repository. When I create a pull request, it starts the checks for the pull request, but it gets stuck on the build step. I am using webpack to build my React app.

**integrate.yml**

```
name: Continous Integration

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  test_pull_request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
          with:
            node-version: '12'

      - name: Cache Dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
          with:
            path: '**/node_modules'
            key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
  
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: yarn test

      - name: Build Project
        run: yarn build:prod
```

**npm scripts**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --env development --open --color --progress",
    "build:prod": "webpack --env production --color --progress",
    "build:dev": "webpack --env development --color --progress",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
},
```

I am assuming that webpack does not stop after it builds the project, and is running in watch mode due to which it is stuck, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Do you have seperate webpack configs for development and production?

Comment: @onuriltan I have single webpack config but some properties are added conditionally based on the environment for example mode and devtool.

Comment: I think you need to add `watch: false` if environment is production and/or try removing  `--progress` from `build:prod`

Comment: I tried add watch: false on local machine but it still does not return control after build is finished. I have to manually do CTRL + C to exit on console. And the progress flag is just to show the percentage while building.

Comment: Can you share webpack config? Do you have `new DashboardPlugin()` in your webpack config? If so you can try deleting it

Comment: I am not using Dashboard plugin in webpack. My doubt was correct, it is indeed due to webpack not exiting after build is complete. I added a compiler hook in the webpack config to exit after build is done. I'll post the detailed solution in a while after testing. Anyways, thanks for the help @onuriltan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was when building project using the `webpack` command, after the build is complete, it does not returns the control and keeps on running. Therefore it gets stuck on the `Build Project` step in the `yaml` file and does not go the next step in Github Actions. The solution is to add a `compiler hook` in the webpack config to exit after the build is complete. This is how I added it in my config and it is working fine now.

```
plugins: [
  // Added this to plugins in webpack config
  {
     apply: (compiler) => {
       compiler.hooks.done.tap('DonePlugin', (stats) => {
         console.log('Compile is done !');
         setTimeout(() => {
           process.exit(0);
         });
       });
     }
  }
]
```